# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘class’

Tags: c++, x11

In XVisualInfo structure there is a property called `class`,
The problem occurs when I want use this structure in c++ program:

```
...
XVisualInfo templ;
templ.screen = screen;
templ.depth = 32;
templ.class = TrueColor;
...
```

When I try to compile I got the error given below:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘class’
templ.class = TrueColor;
      ^~~~~
```

now what can I do to make this works?!!

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as symbol.

Comment: "class" is a reserved keyword in C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that :| but know how can I use X11?!! you mean I should write c?!! and there's no way?

Comment: There are ways to write intermediate shims between bits of C, that are not compatible with C++, and C++. The linked question gives several examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the actual definition of XVisualInfo from `/usr/include/X11/Xutil.h`

```
typedef struct {
  Visual *visual;
  VisualID visualid;
  int screen;
  int depth;
#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(c_plusplus)
  int c_class;                  /* C++ */
#else
  int class;
#endif
  unsigned long red_mask;
  unsigned long green_mask;
  unsigned long blue_mask;
  int colormap_size;
  int bits_per_rgb;
} XVisualInfo;
```

As you can see, the provision to write C++ code is right there. Just use the `c_class` member name.

Comment: Oh ... Thank you :D You saved me. I have to check definitions always!